# Login Screen using Blackberry10 Cascades Development

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-10, blackberry-cascades

I am new to blackberry 10 cascades development. I want to develop a login screen where user name and password will be asked.

If correct credentials are entered it will be redirected to another screen.

On searching i found `NavigationPane` to be used.  Please tell me how to use Navigation Pane for this purpose. Also share some code if possible.

THanks & Regards,

Answer (score 0):

This is as simple as I could make it for you. You haven't specified where your usernames and passwords will be saved (I suggest you NEVER save actual password on a device, if you really need to save just hash!). There is a c++ method missing here (app.checkLogin()) which performs the check. You can also do it in QML if you want.

```
import bb.cascades 1.0

NavigationPane {
    id: navigationPane
    Page {
        Container {
            Label {
                text: "Please log in"
            }
            TextField {
                id: email
                hintText: "Email address"
            }
            TextField {
                id: password
                hintText: "Password"
                inputMode: TextFieldInputMode.Password
            }
            Button {
                text: "Log in"
                onClicked: {
                    if (email.text == "" || password.text == "") {
                        //display error
                        return;
                    }

                    if (app.checkLogin(email.text, password.text)) {
                        //success
                        navigationPane.push(second.createObject());
                    } else {
                        //display error
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    attachedObjects: [
        ComponentDefinition {
            id: second
            source: "second.qml"
        }
    ]
}
```